# android tabwidgets doesnot getting in device

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#808285"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/homeHeaderLayout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="34dp"
    android:background="@drawable/header_bg">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/searchImageView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/header_bg_states"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_search"/>
    <View android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="1.2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/header_divider"/>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/headerLogo"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/header_bg_states"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/madisons_logo"/>
    <View android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="1.2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/header_divider"/>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/shoppingCartImageView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/header_bg_states"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cart"/>
</LinearLayout>
<TabHost android:id="@android:id/tabhost" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:background="@drawable/tabs_bg"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center" 
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:tabStripEnabled="true" 
            style="@style/TabText"/>
        <View android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"/>
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:background="#FFFFFF"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Tabs are not coming in my device... but in emulator they are showing & working. 
my requirement is is work in Google API2.2 version level_8

please anyone can tell me the solution for this